# I want to Toast will show after multiple clicks

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toast

I want to implant toast messages on click but it should show after multiple clicks like we do click on build number 7 times to enable developer option.

I mean toast message should show only after multiple clicks like when we click 3,4 or 5 times.
Toast should not show at first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do, initialize a variable i=0, increment the variable i++ on every click, check when the variable i == 5  then show toast message. If you want the app to remember the value just put in sharedpref file.
Below code for java(android)
here

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
int i;
Button btn;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        i = 0;
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == btn) {
          i++;
           if(i == 5)        //assuming you want click to be five times
            {  
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }  else{
                 int j =5-i;  
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "you are"+j+"steps away", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
    }      
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain it me inside onclicklistner?

Comment: Thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the number of times your view has been clicked and print toast only when the value goes past a point,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var clickCount = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            clickCount++
            if (clickCount > 2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm  just checking if the click count has exceeded 2. Take a look at [that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators).